# Applying ellipsize attribute to the line which is not one line? And how to adjust it

Tags: android, ellipsize

I am trying to make the end of text like '...'. So, what I found is using ellipsize. However, It works well when it is only one line. However, when it becomes more than one line, the last line becomes '...' without any text which I didn't expect. What I want is making the end of the second line '...' as It happens when its just one line without hiding whole the second line but just the end.

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_article_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#B000"
        />
```

this turns out like this below:

[image]

As you can see, 'TITLE' one is one line and ellipsize works fine. However, the second one(in the blue line box) hides all the second line and It just shows '...'. How can I make the second line like 'CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT ...'?

And I am also wondering if there's a way to adjust it even when it's just one line. As you can see, It shows

`TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE...`

But the title area still have at the end some space, I want to make it fill the space like

`TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TIT...`

I couldn't find any information about this. If you don't get it or need more information, please comment.

Comment: Try giving fixed height to TextView with id "content_article_list_layout". Lets say like android:layout_height="44dp".

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but It doesn't work. It is the same result. @mdb